# False 'Security alert' from Google - every login generates mails from 'no-reply@accounts.google.com'

Tags: google, account-security

Every time I log in to Google with the same MacBook I get this email:

```
New device signed in to
    example@gmail.com
Your Google Account was just signed in to from a new Mac device. You're getting this email to make sure it was you.
```

What do these emails mean exactly? When does Google send out those emails?

I guess I receive those emails because I use a VPN (always same public IP address) and some [privacy plugins](https://www.privacytools.io/browsers/#addons) in Firefox.

Comment: Cookie AutoDelete is likely the source of this scenario. Google tracks each browser you use to login using cookies. You can generate the same message when you sign in from a new web browser on the same PC.

Comment: Can you please make me a favor and disable the delete-cookies bluing and leave the VPN, to make sure is it the **changing IP** or the **changing cookies** that triggered this message ?

Comment: *"just signed in to from a new Mac device"* ... You can confuse the server more by changing the `user-agent` header to make it think it's a new Windows, Android, Linux machine.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> I guess I receive those mails because I use a VPN (always same public IP) and some privacy plugins in Firefox.

Yes, this is likely the reason. You use these plugins in order to prevent that the other side can detect that you are the same user on the same device as the previous time. And that's exactly what the mail from Google says: it detected a login from a new device since it could not detect your device as the one you've used before.

That's actually a common compromise one has to take: if privacy or security goes up the usability often goes down. In this case a useful security feature against misuse of your account (security up) conflicted with a useful privacy feature (privacy up) which caused the usability to go down.

Comment: But the message doesn't say "from a new IP address", it says "from a new device". Does that mean the message is incorrect? And if the changing IP is the reason for the alert, why doesn't anyone with a dynamic IP constantly get those messages every hour or whatever that their IP changes? (If not why not)

Comment: @Stilez "from a new device" is much more user friendly than "from a new IP address" for users that are technologically inexperienced, and I imagine that this is the prevailing factor in the choice of phrasing (regardless of whether this is right or wrong).

Comment: @Stilez: The message about "new device" is likely correct, at least more correct than "from a new IP address". Your IP address changes all the time if you have a mobile client which uses various WLAN hotspots, G3..G5 data connections ... . It is the device what counts or more likely the specific browser used by the specific user on the specific device. This combination can be remembered with a permanent cookie in the browser - but if you delete cookies all the time then it cannot remember the device anymore.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy "from a new device" does not mean new IP address. It means a new cookie. When I sign in from a new phone, Google emails me; but when I sign in on my current phone at a new IP address (say, at StarBucks), it does not.

Comment: @jpaugh I know how this works, but that's not what I was addressing. Regardless of what actually happens the driving choice behind the phrasing in such emails will always be usability, never correctness.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy "usability, never correctness." While that's true, the OP explicitly states that the IP address is not changing.

Comment: DreamConspiracy, Steffen - sounds a strange philosophy:  actually wrong information shouldn't ever be presented to the user, because if something goes wrong then it will mislead anyone trying to fix it. But we don't get to choose how Google acts. My own experience is limited, I got this message when using gmail via a 3rd party email app on my phone, where I never signed into Google (mainly as didn't have gapps) and deleted cookies. The message would pop up when I changed WiFi, which suggested it could remember the device +  networks/IPs it had seen the device on, even without cookies.

Comment: @Stilez: if you are using an email app it is likely using IMAP as protocol and not HTTP (as the browser does - and this is what the question is about). IMAP does not support anything like cookies so it cannot rely on this for security checks. This means that it either complains to often (like whenever IP changes) or will not be able to detect if someone (mis)uses the account from a different device but also with IMAP.

Comment: So is it the IP, or the cookies that triggered this message  ?

Comment: @AccountantM: what exactly is done depends on the way you access the account. When you use access the account with an IMAP using mail client instead of a HTTP using browser than it cannot use cookies since IMAP has no concept of cookies. In this case it will likely only report if IMAP is used when it was never used before but not on every change of IP address. When using a browser it can use cookies though to have some permanent marker for the device.

Comment: @Steffen - maybe update the answer to reflect this info about email clients as well, that can't and don't use cookies?

Comment: @Stilez: The question focused on signing into Google using a browser and which impact privacy oriented plugins might have on causing warnings mails about login from a different device. I don't think that the answer should go beyond this scenario and attempt to describe all situations where Google might send such warnings. This would be too far away from the question and apart from that only Google knows when exactly it will send these messages and might change it whenever it likes.

Comment: Even when I use a new browser on the same device, GMail says I signed in from a new device.  Which, by my definition of device, is incorrect.

Comment: @gerrit: These messages are intended for the average user which uses a single browser. While it would be technically more correct to say that somebody logged in with a browser which is has no established relation to Google (i.e. no cookies) this would be too confusing for 99% of the users. And in 99% of the use cases the information "new device" is correct and also easy to understand. Yes, it might confuse 1% of the users but better to confuse 1% instead of 99%.

Comment: _in 99% of the use cases the information "new device" is correct_ Why is it correct? Does that mean that the reason why a certain cookie is not found in a browser is in 99% of the cases that the device is new?

Comment: @SantiBailors: Most users will not delete their cookies. Other reasons the cookie might not be there is that a new browser is used (most users use one), that private mode is used (most don't do it to access mail), that the OS was freshly installed (does not happen that often - and this is kind of a new device then). Again, an overly complicated explanation might be more confusing for the average user than this slightly wrong simplified explanation.

Comment: @SantiBailors: Most users will not delete their cookies. Other reasons the cookie might not be there is that a new browser is used (most users use one), that private mode is used (most don't do it to access mail), that the OS was freshly installed (does not happen that often - and this is kind of a new device then). Again, an overly complicated explanation might be more confusing for the average user than this slightly wrong simplified explanation.

Comment: Sure, I asked only because 99% seems to me a very unreasonably high number, I have no issues with therrest of your explanation, which does make a lot of sense to me.